# How would a hydrogen breathing Life-form respire?

Tags: xenobiology, hydrogen

What kind of cellular structure  converts hydrogen and oxygen to water and vice-versa. If have calculated the energy released by the combustion of oxygen and hydrogen to be 572 kJ enough to create 22 ATP molecules from ADP.
If it is useful the atmospheric composition is:
0% CO2
20% O2
20% H2
50% N2
9% Xe
1% Kr

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello @jhusky, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. When you see that comment by the automated Community BOT, it's a bad sign. It means there's something about your question that fails to meet the minimum standards of Stack Exchange, leading to a high likelihood of closure. In your case, I suspect it's that Stack Exchange permits one and only one question. It needs to be clear and well-focused on a single, specific problem. You're asking multiple questions with a lot of information that's difficult to believe is relevant (e.g., the moon's orbital period). (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... Note that "mixed hydrogen hydrogen oxygen and nitrogen atmosphere" is very confusing (that might have set off the BOT, too). By "hydrogen hydrogen oxygen" do you mean water (H2O)? The phrase "the info about the world is 1/1" is also confusing. Therefore, can you [edit] your question to (a) focus on one, specific question, (b) remove any information that isn't relevant to the question, and (c) review those (and any other) phrases that might be meaningful to you but not to your readers? Thanks!

Comment: One problem with having oxygen and hydrogen in the atmosphere at the same time in significant quantities is that they would naturally react to form water given sufficient initiation energy such as from a UV light or from lightening or a fire.

Comment: The world is covered in only water so fire is highly improbable

Comment: The atmosphere itself would combust and explode upon any spark, such as from a lightning.

Comment: So how much should I change the atmospheric composition so that oxygen and hydrogen are in breathable quantities but won’t explode the entire planet

Comment: Somewhere close to the levels we have in earth, but if it is covered in water its very possible since they would create water.i just dont know how you plan on explaining where it all comes from, and how they separate again in order for you to have that atmosphere

Comment: You can imagine the creatures to be like plants in the day they convert water to oxygen and hydrogen which is like plants creating glucose but in the night the convert the oxygen and hydrogen back into water to release the energy

Comment: I have realised that this is an impossible planet as not only the creatures could not breathe due to the fact that electrolysis is impossible in nature but also that the atmosphere would set on fire with one lightning strike. Therefore I am making the creatures hydrogenotrophic methanogens.

Comment: Sorry, they're right. Your atmosphere is basically 40% rocket fuel. We can see lightning on Jupiter, and that's all it would take to start the reaction. Even if the hydrogen were respirated from your creatures, it would readily combine with oxygen at the first opportunity. There is no rational way you could have enough hydrogen and oxygen for respiration in the same atmosphere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frame challenge:

You cannot really have hydrogen breathing life forms, at least not in the way you want. Hydrogen in elemental form is way too reactive and thus not part of the environment. In fact, oxygen in its elemental form is too reactive, and the only reason it exists in the atmosphere is that it is a byproduct of photosynthesis.

The issue with your calculation is that you also need 572 kJ of energy to separate hydrogen and oxygen from water. And using energy from the sun to create hydrogen and then use it to create ATP is kinda inefficient. And life as a rule doesn't particularly like inefficiency.

Comment: I still don’t know how to stop the atmosphere from setting on fire but I’m thinking that they would use water -> hydrogen and oxygen as a replacement for photosynthesis

Comment: @Jhusky With a 20%/20% H2/O2 mix, the term isn't "setting on fire", it's [detonation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/hydrogen-explosion).  (Though, to be clear, you'd never be able to get to 20% free hydrogen, it would react too quickly.  But if you magically _started_ with that mix, your atmosphere would explode.)

Answer (score -1):

If the question is how do they separate oxigen and hydrogen to breath hydrogen then :
Some kind of electrosis process that would occur naturally, or natural reverse osmosis.

If it is molecular structure:
its all theory so there really isnt anything right or wrong, its like asking what the best hot beverage might be, its Opinion based and grounds for Closure. (Not enough repo to vote/see closure pools)